# How do you query Pods CMS using relationship field?

Tags: wordpress, podscms

I have 2 custom content types created by Pods CMS: fights and events. In the fights content type there is a relationship field for the event. How would I select all fights from the database by a specific event id? I tried querying the pods relationships table manually but that gave me incorrect results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$fights = pods( 'fights' );

$params = array(
    'where' => 'event.id = 3'
);

$fights->find( $params );

// loop through a while( $fights->fetch() ) and use $fights->field() to get the values of each field
```

That should do it, but you'll want to look at the 'find' documentation for your specific content type case as event.id may not be what you want (you may want event.ID).

http://pods.io/docs/code/pods/

http://pods.io/docs/code/pods/find/

http://pods.io/docs/code/pods/field/

http://pods.io/docs/code/pods/display/

Comment: Thanks, but I get the following error: `Unknown column 'event.id' in 'where clause'`

Comment: It works! I was calling the name of the events pod instead of the name of the events field in my fights pod - dumb haha. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Using this function you can easily display all individual relational fields with shortcode:

```
function get_pod_fields($atts) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array('field' => '', 'pod'=> '', 'relation'=> '', 'type'=>'', 'as'=>'url'), $atts );
    $pod = pods( $a['pod'], get_the_id() );
    $related = $pod->field( $a['relation']);
    $field = get_post_meta( $related['ID'], $a['field'], true );
    
    if($a['type'] == "image") {
        if($a['as'] == "image") {
            $field = '<img src="'.$field = $field['guid'].'"></img>';
        } else {
            $field = $field['guid'];
        }
    } else {
        $field = $field;
    }
    return $field;
}
add_shortcode( 'podfields', 'get_pod_fields' );
```

[podfields field="profile_picture"  type="image" pod="therapy" as="image" relation="therapist"]